# How to Decode First Row Only in SQL

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-optimization

I have the following SQL

```
Select decode(:lang_no, 1 , Local_Name , 2 , foreign_Name) Name from Table_Name;
```

The last SQL retrieve about hundreds of thousands of records, and the decode slow down the retrieve, and because :Lang_no is a parameter (which is the same for all records) I want here to tell the optimizer to decode the first row only , So if `:lang_no =1`  it shouldn't check the other records and directly return `Local_Name` , and so on.

So, Is there any Oracle Hint or other tuning idea that can help ?.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the table, the key, the data and how you actually use this query?
Decode is not slow and a couple of hundred thousand records is not a big number.

Comment: How do you know it's the decode that slows down the query? I doubt you can actually measure the performance of that expression.

Comment: Oracle does not provide **dynamic projection** i.e. dynamic column name in SQL query. You can use **Dynamic SQL** to handle such type of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use [`CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) expression?

```
Select CASE 
          WHEN :lang_no = 1 THEN decode(:lang_no, 1 , Local_Name , 2 , foreign_Name) 
          ELSE LocalName 
      END Name 
from Table_Name;
```